# ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_indexing' from 'sklearn.utils'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Whenever I try to run the following line of code:

```py
from imblearn.under_sampling import NearMiss
```

for under-sampling (or over-sampling) imbalanced data on Jupyter notebook, I get this error:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-c701341dce49> in <module>
----> 1 from imblearn.under_sampling import NearMiss

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\under_sampling\__init__.py in <module>
        4 """
        5 
----> 6 from ._prototype_generation import ClusterCentroids
        7 
        8 from ._prototype_selection import RandomUnderSampler

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\under_sampling\_prototype_generation\__init__.py in <module>
        4 """
        5 
----> 6 from ._cluster_centroids import ClusterCentroids
        7 
        8 __all__ = ['ClusterCentroids']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\under_sampling\_prototype_generation\_cluster_centroids.py in <module>
        15 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
        16 from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
---> 17 from sklearn.utils import safe_indexing
        18 
        19 from ..base import BaseUnderSampler

ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_indexing' from 'sklearn.utils' (C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

For imblearn.under_sampling, did you try reinstalling the package?:

```
pip install imbalanced-learn
```

conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

in jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install <package_name>
```

If you have scikitlearn>=0.24 (as far as i see there is a dependency for imblearn now,as scikit-learn (>=0.23) https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/install.html) you may want to try:

```
try:
    from sklearn.utils import safe_indexing
except ImportError:
    from sklearn.utils import _safe_indexing
```

Comment: Do I put scikit-learn for package_name in: !{sys.executable} -m pip install <package_name>? I tried to do so and I keep getting an error saying: The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: It can be any package name, I suggest to try it with imbalanced-learn first (!{sys.executable} -m pip install imbalanced-learn), you can check the dependencies for this package from here https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/install.html.

Comment: I put an edit for the sklearn as well, since i saw that they changed the public/private API. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Even after showing that error message, the jupyter notebook code worked!

Answer (score 1):

Edit *`..\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\ __init__.py`*.

Copy `def _safe_indexing ...` till next `def` and paste the code with renaming to `def safe_indexing...` .

Keep previous `_safe_indexing` as it is.

It solved the issue in this way.

Answer (score 0):

In *`~\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\yellowbrick\classifier\threshold.py`* module replace:

```py
from sklearn.utils import indexable, safe_indexing
```

with

```py
from sklearn.utils import indexable, _safe_indexing
```

After that, restart the kernel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).